# Why my background image is not appearing in the window in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, background

Why my background image is not appearing in the window in pygame?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((1000,437))

background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")

running = True

while running:

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))  
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: You forgot to update your screen. Try adding `pygame.display.flip()` to your code after `screen.blit`. Docs:  [pygame.display.flip](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html?highlight=flip#pygame.display.flip)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update the display with this command: `pygame.display.update()`
Place the command at the end of your while running: loop.

```
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((1000,437))

background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")

running = True

while running:

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))  
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```